# Doctrine Lifecycle PrePersist: get changed property name instead of database column name

Tags: doctrine-orm

When hooking into the PreUpdate lifecycle callback, $eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet seems to return the database column names instead of the object property names.  For example, if you had the following Entity defined:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Something {
    ... 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="some_property", type="integer")
     */
    protected $someProperty;

    ...
}
```

And then you update $someProperty, when your listener is triggered:

```
class Listener {
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs) {
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet());
        die();
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
array (size=1)
  'some_property' =>
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
```

Is there any way to get the array key as 'someProperty' instead of 'some_property'?

Second example for clarity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="full_name", type="integer")
     */
    protected $firstAndLastName;
```

I should get back 'firstAndLastName' instead of 'full_name' as the array key.

Comment: try Doctrine\Common\Inflector::camelize($key)

Comment: I guess rather than just camel casing the result, I'd like to know how to get back the property name instead of the database column.  I've added a second example to the question.